# ON/OFF sound in application Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to create a function that will turn  on/off the sound in the application ?
I have no idea how to do it :( Is it possible to use a system function?

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I have no idea how to do it :( Is it possible to use a system function?

Comment: What do you mean by turn on/off sound do you want to turn your phone to silent?

Comment: @G.hakim I only want to mute the sound of my applications (when run app, alerts etc.)

Comment: Are you using a mediaplayer to play the sounds? what sounds do you have iun your application?

Comment: What kind of sounds do you have in your app

Comment: @G.hakim example for now:  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\Music\app_start.mp3" />
  </ItemGroup>
and
Stream audioStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("xxx.Resources.Music." + "app_start.mp3");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a persistent property that can be read from anywhere in your app and then play the sound only if the muted property is False like this:

You can a have a botton anywhere in your app that toggles the property like this:

```
if (App.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("Muted") && (bool)App.Current.Properties["Muted"])
{
    App.Current.Properties["Muted"] = false;
}
else
{
    App.Current.Properties["Muted"] = true;
}
```

Then whenever you want to play sound you check if the muted property is true, like this:

```
if (App.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("Muted") && (bool)App.Current.Properties["Muted"])
{
    //Play sound here.
}
```